# Suspended uncaught exception Thread [main] (Suspended (uncaught exception InputMismatchException))

Tags: java

I'm just practicing java and at the moment I am currently experimenting with getter/setter methods and constructors. The java program works as I am able to store the user inputs into the object but when I input the String "Dice and rollers" into the gametype string variable, a Suspended uncaught exception InputMismatch error comes up.

This is the error I'm getting whenever I input "Dice and Rollers"
[image]

However, if I use String variables that does not include spaces, it works fine.
[image]

Can someone please explain to me why this is?

Ps. I've shared my source code below.

```
    package test;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test8a {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Please enter the following information: Boardgame name, Alternative Name, Game Type, Year Released, Price and Maximum amount of Players");
        String name = in.next();
        String secondaryname = in.next();
        String type = in.next();
        int date = in.nextInt();
        double price = in.nextDouble();
        int player = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println();
        
        new Test8b(name, secondaryname, type, date, price, player);
    }
}
```

The one above is the superclass while the source code below is the constructor and getter/setter java file.

```
package test;

public class Test8b {
    private String boardname;
    private String secondaryname;
    private String gametype;
    private int date;
    private double price;
    private int numberofPlayers;
    
    public Test8b(String boardname, String secondaryname, String gametype, int date, double price, int players) {
        setBoardname(boardname);
        setSecondaryname(secondaryname);
        setGametype(gametype);
        setDate(date);
        setPrice(price);
        setNumberofPlayers(players);
        
        this.printDetails();
    }

    public String getBoardname() {
        return boardname;
    }
    
    public String getSecondaryname() {
        return secondaryname;
    }

    public String getGametype() {
        return gametype;
    }

    public int getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    
    public int getNumberofPlayers() {
        return numberofPlayers;
    }

    public void setBoardname(String boardname) {
        if (boardname.length() >= 15) {
            System.out.println("There is no boardgame with this name length! Please enter a valid name!");
        } else this.boardname = boardname;
    }
    
    public void setSecondaryname (String secondaryname) {
        if (secondaryname.length() >= 15) {
            System.out.println("There is no boardgame with this name length! Please enter a valid name!");
        } else this.secondaryname = secondaryname;
    }

    public void setGametype(String gametype) {
        this.gametype = gametype;
    }

    public void setDate(int date) {
        if (date > 2021) {
            System.out.println("This game haven't been invented yet or are you a time traveller?");
        } else this.date = date;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        if (price <= 0) {
            System.out.println("Can't give away free games!");
        } else this.price = price;
    }

    public void setNumberofPlayers(int numberofPlayers) {
        if (numberofPlayers <= 0) {
            System.out.println("Need someone to play the game!");
        } else this.numberofPlayers = numberofPlayers;
    }
    
    public void printDetails() {
        System.out.print(
                "Board Game: " + this.getBoardname() + "\n" +
                "Alternative Title: " + this.getSecondaryname() + "\n" +
                "Game Type: " + this.getGametype() + "\n" +
                "Year Released: " + this.getDate() + "\n" +
                "Price: " + this.getPrice() + "\n" +
                "Maximum # of Players: " + this.getNumberofPlayers() + "\n"
                );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is being thrown by the `Scanner` object's `next()` method because the input when you enter a string with spaces does not match the Scanner's default delimiter pattern used for scanning. When you enter a String with spaces, the Scanner sees a line of characters, not just one word of input. In other words, it it differentiates between a single word and a line of words separated by white spaces.

The `java.util.Scanner.nextLine()` method advances the scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped and is the method you should use to scan the game type. Modify your code to use `Scanner.nextLine()` for the game type and any other type that may have multiple words in it.

Comment: Hi, I'd like to follow this up with a new question. I have typed 3 .nextLine() statements after one another. This line works however if I insert a nextInt() statement between those 3 statements, I received the same Input Mismatch exception. Why is that?

Comment: @Jimmy You get an error when you insert a call to `nextInt()' between those calls to `nextLine()` because the scanner isn't looking at a number, it is looking at a string of characters terminated by a new line that don't contain a number.